# Category for measure spaces?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, soft-question, category-theory

I know some things about measures/probabilities and I know some things about categories. Shortly I realized that uptil now I have never encountered something as a category of measure spaces. It seems quite likely to me that something like that can be constructed. I am an amateur however and my scope is small. I have two questions:

> 1 Is there indeed material of this sort and can you tell me about it? The whereabouts for instance.
>
> 2 Is there a reason for the fact that uptil now I did not find anything of the sort? Is it indeed rare for some reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm just going to record some references that you might want to take a look at. They might be a little too heavy on the category theory for your taste, but they also might provide further places to look.

- $n$-Category Café post: [Category Theoretic Probability Theory](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2007/02/category_theoretic_probability.html)
- Related in content, the [nLab article](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/probability+theory) on probability theory; see especially the section "Probability theory from the nPOV"
- The [nLab article](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/measurable+space#related_concepts_19) on measurable spaces. See especially the connection with [von Neumann algebras](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/von+Neumann+algebra#RelationToMeasureSpaces), where it is localizable measurable spaces which are the pertinent concept for the appropriate Gelfand-Naimark duality, and see also references to posts by Dmitri Pavlov at MathOverflow.

Comment: There is also [nLab article on localizable measure spaces](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/localizable+measure)

Answer (score 5):

This has been asked before:

- [Is there an introduction to probability theory from a structuralist/categorical perspective?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical)

And for the notion of product:

- [Can one view the Independent Product in Probability categorially?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120909/can-one-view-the-independent-product-in-probability-categorially)
- [Is there a category structure one can place on measure spaces so that category-theoretic products exist?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49426/is-there-a-category-structure-one-can-place-on-measure-spaces-so-that-category-t)

Comment: Thank you for this. (I know I should avoid comments like this, but I cannot withhold myself from doing it, maybe that comes later)

Comment: *Ego te absolvo*.

Comment: You're briljant! This is my last comment with 'thanks' in it. Next times it will be: *tibi gratias ago* :-). (Last comment, I promise).